# Python Raspberry Pi Adding Functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sensors

I have the below code for when motion is detected i call the camera and email functions. I tried adding the functions after printing Motion Detected but didnt work. Can someone help me where to add the functions? Need it for tomorrow if possible. Thanks

Edit: This is the whole code to help me find the error. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import socket
import datetime
#Camera
import os
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.camera
#Email
import os
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
#Sensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

COMMASPACE = ', '
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

def MOTION(PIR_PIN):
      print(“Motion Detected!”)

print(“PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)”)
time.sleep(2)
print(“Ready”)

try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=MOTION)
    while 1:
           time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print(“ Quit”)
     GPIO.cleanup()


def camera():
width = 480
height = 360

#initialise pygame   
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(width,height))
cam.start()

#setup window
windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),1,16)
pygame.display.set_caption('Camera')

#take a picture
image = cam.get_image()
cam.stop()

#display the picture
catSurfaceObj = image
windowSurfaceObj.blit(catSurfaceObj,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()

#save picture
pygame.image.save(windowSurfaceObj,'picture.jpg')

def email():
sender = ''
gmail_password = ''
recipients = ''
composed = ''

# Create the enclosing (outer) message
outer = MIMEMultipart()
outer['Subject'] = 'MOTION HAS BEEN DETECTED!'
outer['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(recipients)
outer['From'] = sender
outer.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'

# List of attachments
attachments = ['/home/pi/Desktop/picture.jpg']

# Add the attachments to the message
for file in attachments:
    try:
        with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
            msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(msg)
        msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',     filename=os.path.basename(file)) 
        outer.attach(msg)
    except:
        print("Unable to open one of the attachments. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

composed = outer.as_string()

# Send the email
try:
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()
        s.login(sender, gmail_password)
        s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
        s.close()
    print("Email sent!")
except:
    print("Unable to send the email. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

MOTION(PIR_PIN)
```

Comment: If I had to guess, `callback=MOTION` isn't passing any parameters to `def MOTION(PIR_PIN):`

Comment: Do you want me to give you the whole code to check better to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: You have a named parameter. In other words, that PIR_PIN is not the value of 7 as you have defined. From the code examples I've found so far, you should be doing `def MOTION(7):`

Comment: I have edited the Question and added the whole code. Thanks

Comment: By the way the error is in Line 120 where there is MOTION() at the last

Comment: Ok, same problem... You need to specify a value for the parameter... You can't just call MOTION() with no value

Comment: Thanks very much but now after it detects i am getting this error:

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional information. Try not to use the comments for code or errors

Comment: I posted an answer with the error. Thanks

Comment: I've never used these methods, but that error seems clear to say that you've already established edge detection on that channel, so you don't need to do whatever you are doing again